# What is the probability of product of two elements is desired element?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group with $n$ element. Fix $x\in G$.

If you choose randomly two elements from $G$, what is the probability of $x$ being product of these two elements?

At first, I thought answer was $1/n$, because, if $ab=x$ and if I choose $a$, it uniquely determines $b$. I guess it is true answer when $G$ is abelian.

But when $G$ is nonabeliean, $ab$ and $ba$ may be different elements; therefore, the probability is higher than $1/n$. I can't say the answer is $2/n$ since some pairs may still commute in nonabelian group.

I also noticed that the probability also depends on $x$, because, if $x=e$, you must choose $a,a^{-1}$ as a pair, so answer is $1/n$ regardless of $G$ is abelian or not.

If we denote this probability as $P_x(G)$, I think $1/n\leq P_x(G)\leq 2/n$.

Any further result will be appreciated.

As  Geoff Robinson request let me clarify what I mean,

Let $w\in GxG$ i,e, $w=(a,b)$ let  say that $w$ know answer if $ab=x$ or $ba=x$.

What is the probability that $w$ know the answer?

Comment: I think you have to decide what question you are asking. If you think of the pair as an ordered pair, you will get a different answer to that which you would get thinking about an unordered pair. Also you need to decide if you way to choose the group elements with or without replacement. This is not a contradiction: there are $|G|^{2}$ ordered pairs and $|G|(|G|-1)/2$ unordered pairs of genuinely distinct elements).

Comment: you can choose $a,a$ also ,I mean these two elements need not be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could equally ask for the probability with ordered or unordered pairs, with different results.

It suffices to count the number of pairs $a,b$ satisfying $x=ab\vee x=ba$, where $x\in G$ is fixed.

Say we wish to count ordered pairs of not necessarily distinct elements. Notice the equivalence $x=ab\vee x=ba\iff b=a^{-1}x\vee b=xa^{-1}$. If we naively count two $b$s for each $a\in G$ be overcounting by one for each $a$ satisfying $a^{-1}x=xa^{-1}$, the number of which is $|C_G(x)|$, where $C_G(x)$ is the centralizer of $x$. So we conclude the number of pairs is $2|G|-|C_G(x)|$.

The corresponding probability is $$P=\frac{2|G|-|C_G(x)|}{|G|^2}. \tag{ordered}$$

Define $\sqrt{x}:=\{a\in G:x=a^2\}$, the set of "square roots" of $x$. Let $\Pi:=(x=ab\vee x=ba)$.

Suppose we wish to count the unordered pairs of not necessarily distinct elements satisying $\Pi$; say there are $N$ such pairs. If we take $N$ and subtract $|\sqrt{x}|$ we will have the number of unordered pairs of distinct elements satisfying $\Pi$. If we then multiply by two we will have the number of ordered pairs of distinct elements satisfying $\Pi$. If we then add on $|\sqrt{x}|$ we will have the number of ordered pairs of not necessarily distinct elements satisfying $\Pi -$ we already know this number. Therefore,

$$2\left(N-|\sqrt{x}|\right)+|\sqrt{x}|=2|G|-|C_G(x)|\iff N=|G|+\frac{|\sqrt{x}|-|C_G(x)|}{2}.$$

We wound up proving $|C_G(x)|\equiv|\sqrt{x}|$ mod $2$. The total number of unordered pairs of not necessarily distinct elements of $G$ is $(|G|^2+|G|)/2$. Therefore the corresponding probability is

$$P=\frac{2|G|+|\sqrt{x}|-|C_G(x)|}{|G|^2+|G|}. \tag{unordered}$$

If you force the elements to be distinct, the probabilities then become

$$P=\frac{2|G|-|\sqrt{x}|-|C_G(x)|}{|G|^2-|G|}, \tag{distinct}$$

for both ordered and unordered pairs.

Comment: it seems reasonable, let me think.

Comment: So,$P_x=1/n$ if and only if $x\in Z(G)$,this also explain the case when $G$ is abelian. Thanks.

Comment: If you sum this probability over all $x \in G,$ you will get $\frac{2|G|^{2} - k(G)|G|}{|G|^{2}}$, where $G$ has $k(G)$ conjugacy classes.This will be greater than $1$ unless $G$ is Abelian.

Comment: Yes,with same reason, I opened my computer again since $\sum_{x\in G}P_x=1 \implies \sum_{x\in G}|C_G(x)|=|G|^2 \implies $ average of $|C_g(x)|=|G|$ which is only true in abelian groups.

Comment: @Geoff Correct, when you add up these probabilities it will be greater than $1$. Note that $x\ne y$ doesn't mean $x=ab\vee x=ba$ and $y=ab\vee y=ba$ are mutually exclusive, so this is to be expected.

Comment: Which suggests to me that the original problem was not well defined.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson The original problem is to calculate the probability that $(a,b)$, picked uniformly from $G\times G$, is such that $x=ab$ or $x=ba$, where $x$ is some fixed element of $G$. Just because an indexed family of events are not mutually exclusive doesn't mean it's ill-defined to ask what each's probability is. For example, say $X=\{1,\cdots,100\}$. For each $1\le x\le 100$ we can ask "what's the probability that $a\in X$ picked uniformly is divisible by $x$"? If you add these probabilities up over $x=1,\cdots,100$ you will get a value bigger than $1$, but the question is well-defined.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I think there is absolutely no ambiguity that OP was talking about $x=ab\vee x=ba$ and not just $x=ab$. However I agree the wording left it unclear whether they were talking about ordered or unordered pairs. When I come back I will address the unordered case.

Comment: @anon: Let $G$ be a group with odd order, then it is easy to show that $f(x)=x^2$ is a bijection from $G$ to $G$.That means that $\sqrt x$ is uniqe.
Thus,$|\sqrt x|=1$ and when I put them into the your equation and try to solve $\sum_x(P_x)=1$ I will get $\sum_x(C_G(x))=G^2$ which is not true for all groups with odd order. ?????

Comment: correction; $G^2$ should be replaced by $|G|^2$ and  $C_G(x)$ should be replaced as $|C_G(x)|$ in above equality.

Comment: @Geoff From the beginning I have been clear I am talking about $x=ab\vee x=ba$, not $x=ab$ or $x=ba$ in isolation. The $4$th paragraph of the OP also made that clear. This means we are computing $$\frac{\#\{(a,b)\in G\times G:x=ab\vee x=ba\}}{|G\times G|}$$ as a function of $x\in G$. If you're unfamiliar with the symbol $\vee$, it is called *logical disjunction*, which means (inclusive) "or." The OP even updated their question (for you specifically) just to clarify that they meant "$ab=x$ or $ba=x$."

Comment: With my Ctrl+F function I see that you are the only person here to put the word "the" before the word "product," contrary to your suggestion that I've used the phrase "the product" somewhere. I know how to do the problem with just $x=ab$ in isolation, and I know that the probabilities add up to $1$ in that case because the events $x=ab$ as $x$ ranges over $G$ are collectively exhaustive and mutually exclusive events - but the problem is boringly trivial in that case (the OP solved that in a single sentence).

Comment: @mesel The issue with your comment is that $\sum_{x\in G}P_x=1$ is *not true*, and we *shouldn't expect it to be true*. The reason is that the events whose probabilities you're trying to compute are not *mutually exclusive events*; they have some overlap. Let $E_x$ be the event $x=ab\vee x=ba$ (i.e. the set of pairs of $G\times G$ for which that proposition is satisfied). Suppose $a,b\in G$ don't commute. Then $(a,b)$ is in both $E_{ab}$ and $E_{ba}$, so $E_{ab}\cap E_{ba}\ne\varnothing$ even though $ab\ne ba$. I also discussed this with Geoff above; see my example with $X=\{1,\cdots,100\}$.

Comment: @anon: I am not good at probability,I had thougt that $\sum_x (P_x)=1$ is always true. Is it my conclusion true? $w$ know the answer with chance $1/n$ if $a,b$ commutes and know the answer with chance $2/n$ if $a,b$ does not commute. let $Q_\{{a,b}\}$ be probability that they commutes.Then,I claims $P_x=Q_\{{a,b}\}/n+(1-Q_\{{a,b}\}2/n)$? Since we already $P_x$, I want to find $Q$,if it is true.

Comment: @mesel If you take a probability space and partition it into collectively exhaustive, mutually exclusive events, then those events will each have a probability in $[0,1]$, and the sum of those probabilities will be $1$, as you indicate. However as I said, we are not in that situation, because the events we are talking about (indexed by $x\in G$) are not mutually exclusive. I gave an example with $X=\{1,\cdots,100\}$ to show we can have a family of events indexed by the elements of a probability space which are not mutually exclusive. I am unable figure out what the rest of your comment says.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13419/discussion-between-mesel-and-anon)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a,b$ are uniformly and independently distributed: $P(ab=g\mid a=c)=P(b=a^{-1}g)=\frac{1}{n}$. Now sum over $c$ to get $P(ab=g)=\sum _{c\in G}P(ab=g\mid a=c)\cdot P(a=c)$ to get $\frac{1}{n}$ as the final answer.

Comment: The OP is asking about $x=ab\vee x=ba$.

Comment: Yes,for any pair $(a,b)$ if $ab=x$ or $ba=x$ we are done,I guess this change the probability.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning in the case that $x = e$ is perfectly good, and would work just as well with other group elements. There are $|G|^{2}$ ordered pairs $(a,b)$ and for every $x \in G$ there are precisely $|G|$ ordered pairs $(a,b)$ such that $ab= x.$

Comment: The OP is asking about $x=ab\vee x=ba$.

Comment: This was not clear, which is why I put the earlier comment.

Comment: Your comment was asking about pairs vs. ordered pairs, which is different from $x=ab$ vs. $x=ab\vee x=ba$.